# Xcode Simulator: How do I get the settings "Screen time"?

Tags: testing, in-app-purchase, app-store, ios-simulator, sandbox

I try to test in app purchases with sandbox users. Unfortunately I always get the error "Cannot connect to itunes store". All bug fixes I've seen mention you should reset some settings in the "Screen time" section of the settings app. However, I don't have any screen time in the settings app. What am I missing? iOS version is 13.3 of the test device. I've also tried to login to the itunes account with the sandbox user, but this doesn't work of course. So what am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app purchase testing on the simulator is impossible. Test only on a device. When you run the app from Xcode, the sandbox user will be used automatically; no need to sign out of your normal user. Even simpler, use TestFlight.